# runtime error c++ when passing array to function via pointer

Tags: c++

I am a novice at programming and I have to finish this task for my cs class. The task is given within the source code.

```
/**@file Activity_3_1.cpp
 * @brief Activity 3.1 Gives Basic Practice for Arrays.
 * <PRE>
 * Activity 3.1
 * Gives Basic Practice for Arrays.
 * 1. Write a function to fill integer Array, size of the array participants can
 * choose. The function should take an array - which is to be filled - and a
 * size of array as its arguments.
 * 2. Write function to print the contents of an integer array. The function
 * should take an array and a size of array as its arguments.
 * 3. Write a funciton to find the sum total of the integer array element. The
 * function should take an array and a size of array as its arguments.
 * 4. Write a function to find the Average of the integer array element. The
 * function should take an array and a size of array as its arguments.
 * 5. Write a main function which utilizes all above functions, and print the
 * output of each function.
 * 6. For each of the above participants can choose their own algorithms.
 * </PRE>
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/**@fn fillArray(const int sizeOfArray)
 * @brief Fills the Array.
 * function to fill array. it takes the size of the array and based on that
 * takes elements from the user.
 * @param array int []
 * @param sizeOfArray const int
 */
// function to fill array. it takes the size of the array and based on that
// takes elements from the user.

void fillArray(int *array, const int sizeOfArray);

/**@fn printArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray)
 * @brief prints the Array.
 * function to print the array. It takes array and the sizeOfArray as arguments.
 * @param array int []
 * @param sizeOfArray const int
 */
// function to print the array. It takes array and the sizeOfArray as arguments.
void printArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray);

/**@fn sumTotalOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray)
 * @brief find the total of array elements.
 * funciton to find the sum-total of array. Takes array and it's size as
 * arguments.
 * @param array int []
 * @param sizeOfArray const int
 */
// funciton to find the sum-total of array. Takes array and it's size as
// arguments.
int sumTotalOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray);

/**@fn averageOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray)
 * @brief finds the average of array elements.
 */
// function to find the average of the array. Utilizes the sumTotalFunction.
// Arguments are Array and Size of Array.
double averageOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray);

void fillArray(int *array, const int sizeOfArray) {
  for (int i; i > sizeOfArray; i++) {
    cout << "ievadiet elementa " << i << " vertibu : ";
    cin >> array[i];
    cout << "\n";
  }
  //  return array;
}

void printArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray) {
  for (int i; i > sizeOfArray; i++) {
    cout << i << " elementa vertiba : " << array[i] << "\n";
  }
}

int sumTotalOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray) {
  int sumTotal;
  for (int i; i > sizeOfArray; i++) {
    sumTotal += array[i];
  }
  return sumTotal;
}

double averageOfArray(const int array[], const int sizeOfArray) {
  double average;
  average = sumTotalOfArray(array, sizeOfArray) / sizeOfArray;
  return average;
  // Uses the sumTotalArray to find the sum total. it coverts the sum to double
  // to have average in decimal.
  //  //Write Your Code Here
}

int main() {
  // Defines a constant for the size of array.
  const int arraySize = 20;
  // Initializes array elements to zero.
  int myArray[arraySize];
  for (int i; i > arraySize; i++) {
    myArray[i] = 0;
  }
  // fills the array.
  fillArray(myArray, arraySize);
  // prints the array
  printArray(myArray, arraySize);
  // finds the average of the array.
  double myaverage = averageOfArray(myArray, arraySize);
  cout << "this is the average: " << myaverage << "\n";
}
```

the runtime error started coming up when I tried to make the program pass myArray to the fillArray function via a pointer, so I'm pretty sure that that is what is causing my problems.
The array is supposed to be filled by the user, so I'm trying to give the function access to the actual array that is in main's scope. I've compared my program with other examples of this I can find online, and I can't find the mistake.

the program shows this upon execution:

```
"Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) execution time : 0.434 s Press any key to continue."
```

Comment: All your loop conditions are wrong.

Comment: `i > sizeOfArray` should be `i < sizeOfArray` Also you are not initializing i.

Comment: The error `0xC0000005` is an access violation (segfault). I see numerous answer where posted at the same time all indicating the source of the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your for loops:

```
for (int i;i> arraySize; i++)
{
    myArray[i]=0;
}
```

1. You need to initialise `i`, because in C++ it won't assume a default value if you don't.
2. `i> arraySize` means "`i` is *greater than* the array size", which is the opposite of what you want.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

For what it's worth, the way I was taught to remember which way round `>` and `<` are was to imagine the symbol as a crocodile's mouth that always eats the biggest fish... :-)

Comment: To clarify, the middle statement in a `for` loop is a *while* condition.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty a while condition, rather. If it's initially false, the loop body isn't executed.

Comment: Fixed; that's true.  I should finish my coffee before getting on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

You have blundered all of your for-statements.

```
  for (int i; i > arraySize; i++)...
```

Should read

```
  for (int i= 0; i < arraySize; i++)...
```

I.e. start at 0, count up while `i < arraySize`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the for-loops are wrong: They should look like

```
for(int i = <start value>; i < arraySize; i++)
```

otherwise you risk uninitialized i's and wrong loops causing memory read/write bugs.